# My localized image captions (from meta data) don't get loaded in the FE (just the default language)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.27. We are using a custom FAL-Driver, which creates localized Meta-Data for the FAL-Records. But in the frontend we get only the meta data with the sys_language_uid 0 (for example in the caption). The database entries look fine.

I've digged into the core and found the FilesContentObject which is responsible for rendering the textpic. This loads the files from the database. The metadata gets loaded in the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File` class. This finally calls the `MetaDataRepository::findByFileUid()`. This doesn't respect the current sys_language but adds a Default constraint to the Query:

```
protected function getGeneralWhereClause() {
    return ' AND sys_language_uid IN (0,-1) AND pid=0';
}
```

Who in this chain is responsible for adding the correct sys_language constraint? I think this should be done by the MetaDataRepository, but I don't know much of the internals.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the default core driver it works fine or does that one give you issues too?

Answer (score 1):

The language overlay in the front-end happens in this aspect https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Aspect/FileMetadataOverlayAspect.php